# How to get sum by groups in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, summary

I want to get the sum by the groups in Crystal Reports.

```
Group OVERALL
-----------------
      group 1
     --------------
          5.00
          5.00
         10.00
     --------------
     total group 1      20.00
     --------------
      group 2
      --------------
         10.00
         25.00
         15.00
      --------------
     total group 2      50.00
-------------------
Total Group OVERALL     70.00
```

Using this formula `sum({field.amount}, {field.group})` I only get sum for OVERALL but not for group 1 and 2.

Comment: You need to sum over inner group - easiest way is to place summary fields (not formuals) into correct sections and CR takes care of correct grouping fields itself.

Comment: i add a running total..and place it in perspective grouping fields but what i does it just sums up its group total..like group total 1 = 20 and the total group 2 it becomes 70 which is it should be 50..why is that sir ?

Comment: Do not use running total, but normal summarised field.

Answer (score 8):

1. Right Click field which you want to Sum
2. Select Insert -> Summary and select Group On field below on the same dialog window
3. Click Ok