# How to show sum of group total in crystal report 11?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi

I am new to crystal report. I wants to show sum of group total like below.

```
Item Code Group 1               (1000)   //negative
     item1               2000
     item2               -3000

Item Code Group 1                2000      //Positive
     item1               4000
     item2               -2000

               sum of grouping = 1000
```

I tried these two links [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34333464/how-to-get-sum-by-groups-in-crystal-report) , [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388243/how-to-get-sum-of-groups-in-crystal-report-10) but I did not get the exact output

I am using crystal report 11

Comment: are you trying for grand total?

Comment: What if you insert a Summation of the value field on the Report footer. It should work out the calculation itself (unless you have custom filters in the detail level.)